# Create online regression tests for code snippets on CodePen

Tags: javascript, web-services, regression-testing

**tl;dr**

Is there an online service or something similar that allows writing regression tests (e.g. using Jasmine or Karma) for code snippets hosted on CodePen.io?

**Broader picture**

I want to create a community driven resource of accessible code snippets. The snippets should be hosted on CodePen. Whenever somebody forks a code snippet and proposes a better version, I want to import this new version into my database.

To make sure that no existing functionality breaks, I need regression tests for each code pen (using e.g. Jasmine or Karma). As accessibility is very cross browser relevant, those tests need to be run in different browsers, e.g. Internet Explorer 11 and newest Firefox version (Win).

So it would be great to have an online service where one can create JavaScript regression tests, so each code pen has a respective test. And when importing a new version of a code snippet, the regression test would automatically be triggered, and import would only be successful if the test passes on all specified browsers. So this would need an API to this online service with which I can trigger the test and receive a `pass` or `fail` result.

Comment: You can put your snippets in a GitHub repo, add tests there, then have an integrated CI service run the tests. Committing to GitHub from CodePen could be done by something like https://lucusp.github.io/CodePanion/

Comment: That's a good hint with CodePanion. Thank you.